# Selenium in headless mode doesn't work with user profiles

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, browser, selenium-chromedriver, chromium

Im trying to run headless tests in selenium with a userprofile so that the browser's logged in on the site I want to run my tests on.

Everything below runs fine:

```
from selenium import webdriver

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.headless = False
options.add_argument('window-size=1400,600')
options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)
options.add_argument("user-data-dir=accs/_"+"cauchysc") 

driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, executable_path="/home/user/Downloads/chromedriver_linux64/chromedriver")
print("A")
driver.get('http://www.yahoo.com')
print(driver.page_source)
driver.save_screenshot('./save_screenshot_method.png') #Capture the screen
driver.quit()
```

However, as soon as I add the `options.headless=True` The site "yahoo.com" never loads and the test runs forever until the TimeoutException.

Im using the latest ChromeDriver 87.0.4280.20 and Google chrome Version 87.0.4280.66 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Update:

Following recommendations, I removed the add_experimental_option lines.

The error stack trace:

```
TimeoutException                          Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-17-7d8202049c6c> in <module>
     10 driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, executable_path="/home/user/Downloads/chromedriver_linux64/chromedriver")
     11 print("A")
---> 12 driver.get('http://www.yahoo.com' class="ansi-blue-fg">)
     13 print(driver.page_source)
     14 driver.save_screenshot('./save_screenshot_method.png') #Capture the screen

~/anaconda3/envs/myenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py in get(self, url)
    331         Loads a web page in the current browser session.
    332         """
--> 333         self.execute(Command.GET, {'url': url})
    334 
    335     @property

~/anaconda3/envs/myenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py in execute(self, driver_command, params)
    319         response = self.command_executor.execute(driver_command, params)
    320         if response:
--> 321             self.error_handler.check_response(response)
    322             response['value'] = self._unwrap_value(
    323                 response.get('value', None))

~/anaconda3/envs/myenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py in check_response(self, response)
    240                 alert_text = value['alert'].get('text')
    241             raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace, alert_text)
--> 242         raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
    243 
    244     def _value_or_default(self, obj, key, default):

TimeoutException: Message: timeout: Timed out receiving message from renderer: 298.701
  (Session info: headless chrome=87.0.4280.66)
```

Comment: Update the question with the text based error stack trace.

Comment: Does it work when you remove those add_experimental_option lines?

Comment: @DebanjanB I have added the error stack trace. The error occurs in the driver.get stage

Comment: @DMart I removed the add_experimental_option lines and reran the code, things still do not work.

Comment: and this is with all URLs?